# Название организации

Tags: кавычки

Допустим, организация называется "Союз любителей пива". Но зарегистрированное название - Всероссийская общественная организация "Союз любителей пива".
Как будет правильно: члены Союза любителей пива или члены "Союза любителей пива"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Юридически правильно только *члены ВОО "Союз любителей пива"*. 
А в обычном тексте более или менее правильным могут считаться считаться оба варианта: *члены "Союза любителей пива"* - как прямое название организации, *члены Союза любителей пива* - как описательное. Первое, закавыченнное, думаю, предпочтительнее в силу своей большей универсальности.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: члены Союза любителей пива. Реальные собственные имена( различающиеся синтаксической сочетаемостью) в кавычки не берутся. В вашем случае синтаксически зависимое название, поэтому кавычки не нужны.Подробнее здесь: [Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=kav2)
.

Comment: Не тот случай. То, на что вы сослались, относится к вопросы о необходимости закавычивать не всю конструкцию, а только то, что идет после родового слова "союз". Тут кавычек, согласен, не требуется. Да так вопрос и не стоит. 

У нас, скорее уж реальное имя - ВОО "Союз любителей пива".
А "Союз любителей пива" - условное название. Ничем не отличается от <<союза "Меча и Орала">>.

Comment: Да. Этот момент я в Грамоте прочитала, но вот что смутило. Если официальное название - это "Союз любителей пива", то вопросов нет, кавычки не нужны. А если официальное название - Всероссийская общественная организация... Вот тут уже сомнения.

Comment: У двух союзов писателей тоже есть приставка (ООО) - крупные общественные организации проходят юридическую регистрацию.

Answer (score 2):

Члены (Всероссийской общественной) **организации** (ВОО) **"Союз любителей пива"**, либо **члены Союза любителей пива**. Первое может понадобиться в начале материала - для представления малоизвестной организации. А в случае более известной и уважаемой Общероссийской общественной организации (ООО) "Союз российских писателей" достаточно сказать: члены Союза российских писателей. Если же написать *члены "Союза любителей пива"* (что возможно в ряде контекстов), это станет неформальным выражением скептического отношения пишущего к этой организации, который недавно услышал её название.

Comment: Спасибо! У меня есть еще один "мутный" для меня вопрос по названиям. Можно сюда? Или лучше отдельно?

Comment: Лучше отдельно.

Comment: И без ошибок в шапке вопроса. Глаза режет. Спасибо