# Название. Кавычки и региональная принадлежность

Tags: прописная-строчная, пунктуация

Юридические нюансы: Организация Всероссийская, у нее есть региональные отделения, которые официально регистрируются и называются Челябинское региональное отделение Всероссийской общественной организации "Союз волшебников России" (допустим). Между собой члены организации называют ее отделения ЧудоЦентр (т.е. буквально центры в которых делают чудесные дела).
Вопрос 1: Нужно ли ЧудоЦентр заключать в кавычки?
Вопрос 2: Активисты челябинского ЧудоЦентра (т.е. активисты Челябинского регионального отделения....). "челябинского" здесь - это часть названия и писать с большой буквы или географический указатель, а буква маленькая?

Answer (score 2):

> Вопрос 1: Нужно ли ЧудоЦентр заключать в кавычки?

Да. Это же название никто пока не утвердил официально и в словарях его нет.

> Вопрос 2: Активисты челябинского ЧудоЦентра (т.е. активисты Челябинского регионального отделения....). "челябинского" здесь - это часть названия и писать с большой буквы или географический указатель, а буква маленькая?

Это наверняка можно сказать только посмотрев учредительные документы. Но скорее все-таки - география. И буква потому строчная.

Comment: Оказалось, что это название присутствует в учредительных документах. Вот в таком случае кавычки остаются?

Comment: Что именно присутствует? Слово "челябинский"? 
Приведите полное название из учредительных документов.  

Кавычки (внутри названия) могут понадобиться в том случае, если они есть в самом названии или если вы приводите полное название в сочетании с каким-то родовым словом. *Остальные случаи необходимого закавычивания к нашему обсуждению, вроде, не относятся.*

Comment: Учредительных документов пока не видела. Но мне сказали, что именно там присутствует слово "Чудоцентр" или "ЧудоЦентр"

Comment: Ну тогда лучше все-таки посмотреть точно. Написание самого этого изобретенного слова (включая кавычки) должно соответствовать учредительным документам. Это же касается и внешних кавычек - вокруг всей конструкции "челябинский ДатаЦентр" - но это уже тогда, когда вы используете его с родовым словом (предприятие "челябинский Чудоцентр"). Другого способа упорядочить написание я тут не вижу.

Comment: Что касается соображения Сержа, то они теоретически правильны. Но беда в том, что без привлечения "высших сил" невозможно точно квалифицировать, чем является это "чудоцентр", вернее в каком качестве оно выступает: новопридуманного нарицательного, родового слова или хитрого названия.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего, надо убрать заглавную букву из середины слова (чудо-центр). Если наименование филиала неформальное, нельзя требовать от остальных трактовать его как название организации, для них это т.н. челябинский "чудо-центр" (челябинский филиал организации "Союэ..." - как пояснительная расшифровка). "Челябинский" с большой буквы писать нужно только в составе официального названия филиала, если оно с этого слова начинается (напр. Региональная ОО "Челябинское отделение Союза волшебников России").

Comment: На большую букву и дефис повлиять не могу пока. Т.е. в таком случае правильно писать челябинский "ЧудоЦентр"? Или лучше вообще исключить из статей это название и ограничиться официальным?

Comment: Лучше официальным пользоваться. А где неофициальное зафиксировано письменно? Пока известен один случай регистрации названия, выбранного с нарушением норм орфографии: МегаФон.

Comment: Не зарегистрировано. На сайте организации используется в статьях

Comment: >Пока известен один случай регистрации названия, выбранного с нарушением норм орфографии: МегаФон.  
  
Их таких до черта.  
  
>Не зарегистрировано. На сайте организации используется в статьях  
  
Тогда никаких заглавных в середине слова быть не должно. Остальное уж как хотите. Лучше, конечно, поближе к привычному: "Чудоцентр"

Answer (score 1):

Активисты челябинского ЧудоЦентра (в этом случае кавычки не требуются). О причинах - см. ответ на предыдущий ваш вопрос. [Название организации](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/43167/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: А что насчет этого ответа: " Да. Это же название никто пока не утвердил официально и в словарях его нет"??? Слово же выдуманное

Comment: При чем тут выдуманное или нет? Из ответа получается, что если название неофициальное, его надо заключать в кавычки, а официальное - нет. Но вы невнимательно прочли 2 моих ответа. Кавычки не требуются в данном конкретном случае,поскольку здесь реальное собственное имя( различающееся синтаксической сочетаемостью). Реальное имя тоже может употребляться в кавычках, если употребляется с родовым словом. Ср.напр.: **Государственная академия славянской культуры и образовательное учреждение "Государственная академия славянской культуры"** То же в вашем случае.

Comment: Кавычки можно употребить в следующем случае: Неформальное название челябинских филиалов организации "Союэ..." -  **''ЧудоЦентр"**. Хотя предложение получается слишком витиеватое, и стилистически небрежное. Я его привел для того, чтобы пояснить употребление кавычек. А так, читайте ответ Александра. Он дал исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Я Вас поняла, а переспросила из-за ответа Ирины.